# Weekly Steel Gain From Orders

Tags: for-honor

Is the amount of steel you'll earn in 1 week from the rewards for completing orders constant, assuming you complete them all?  If so, how much is it?  If not, is there a typical range?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
There have been some changes to how orders work and new orders added since I posted this answer.  I have not had the chance to figure it out again since the changes, but I'll leave my old answer below until I can update it.

---

**tl;dr**

Yes, the rewards are constant, and the total amount is 6,600 steel.

**Show Your Work**

From my experience, I believe all daily orders reward 300 steel on completion, and all contract orders reward 100 steel (I'm not going to consider special community events, since the rewards vary and I don't think they are regularly scheduled).  There are 2 new daily orders each day, and 6 contract orders on Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday, and Sunday.  Crunching the numbers:

2 daily orders * 7 days a week * 300 steel per order = 4200 steel per week

6 contract orders * 4 times a week * 100 steel per order = 2400 steel per week

4200 for daily orders + 2400 for contract orders = **6600 steel per week**

**But Wait, There's More**

Note that this number only reflects steel gained from the reward for the order.  Orders are all based on completing a certain number of games of a certain type under certain conditions, so you will gain steel as loot from completing those games.  These calculations don't consider this "loot" steel, so the actual steel gain in a week will be higher, but will depend on the number and type of matches played to complete the order.